# Reading file contents section by section

Tags: c, file, data-structures, struct

I am trying to read a file contents in sections into useable structs, the '#' symbol begins a section while the '.' symbol ends it. An example would be:

```
# Type name
bird
mammal
.
# Type effectiveness
VeryEffective
NotEffective
.
```

So far I can read the contents of the first type, but when I try to read the contents of the second, I keep re-reading the contents of the first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    typedef struct 
    {
        char types[1000];
        char effectiveness[1000];
    } sinFile; 
    sinFile record[1000];

    FILE* file; 
    char line[121];
    char period[10];
    char Type2[20];


    char* item; 
    char* item2;
    int i = 0;
    int j;


    file = fopen("Test3.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, 120, file)) {
        item = strtok(line, " ");
        strcpy(period, ".");
        strcpy(Type2, "# Type effectiveness");

        if (item[0] == '#' || item[0] == '.') {
            continue;
        } else {
            do {
                strcpy(record[i].types, line);
                i++;
            } while (strcmp(record[i].types, period) == 0);
        }


        for(j=0; strcmp(line, Type2) == 0; j++) { 
            do {
                strcpy(record[j].effectiveness, line);
                j++;
            } while (strcmp(record[j].effectiveness, period)== 0);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    printf("%s", record[1].effectiveness);
}
```

Currently, record[1].types gives me the same result as record[1].effectiveness; i.e. 'mammal'. I feel like I am close but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Fyi, `"# Type effectiveness"` is **21** chars wide, including the terminator. You're breaching your `Type2` array.

Comment: Is there always one word per line in the file?

Comment: In order to test, I have simplified the file but only the contents in '# Type effectiveness' contain more than one word.

Comment: This code has many many issues... The main problem seems to be, in both do..while loops line is copied, but no fgets was made. The strcmp in the while() uses record[i] which is undefined.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256827/differentiating-data-in-a-file-c. Please do not double-post.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in this code. To get it worked something like this sample should be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    typedef struct 
    {
        char types[1000];
        char effectiveness[1000];
    } sinFile; 

    sinFile record[1000];

    FILE* file; 
    char line[121];
    char* bp; 
    int i=0, j=0;
    int state=0;

    file = fopen("Test3.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, 120, file)) {
        for(bp=line;isspace(*bp);bp++);
        if(state==0) {
            if(*bp=='#') {
                for(bp=line;isspace(*bp);bp++);
                item = bp;
                if(!strcmp(item,"Type name")) state=1;
                else if(!strcmp(item,"Type effectiveness")) state=2;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(*bp=='.') {
                state=0;
            }
            else if(state==1) {
                strcpy(record[i].types, bp);
                i++;
            }
            else if(state==2) {
                strcpy(record[j].effectiveness, bp);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    printf("%s", record[1].effectiveness);
}
```

But with this code, the lines in the 1st block have to correspond with the lines in the 2nd block... It would be simpler to use key/value-pairs without blocks.